# Normal Lie subgroup is contained in the centre

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Show that any proper normal Lie subgroup $H$ of $G$ is contained in the centre of $G$.

I know that if $H$ is discrete. Then the result holds by [discrete normal subgroup of a connected group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287155/discrete-normal-subgroup-of-a-connected-group). One approach is to show that any proper normal Lie subgroup is discrete. But to show this it involves the use of manifolds, which I'm trying to avoid.

Another approach I have in mind is to use that $Z(G)=\ker(ad)$ from [Centre of a connected Lie group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469553/centre-of-a-connected-lie-group). And show that $H$ is in $ker(ad)$. Since $H$ is a normal Lie subgroup, it must be the kernel of some Lie homomorphism map. But I'm not sure how to show that $H\subset Ker(ad)$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a correspondence between normal subgroups of $G$ and ideals of $\mathfrak g$. Since $H$ is normal in $G$, then $\mathfrak h$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak g$. But $\mathfrak g$ is simple, so either $\mathfrak h = \{0\}$ or $\mathfrak h = \mathfrak g$. In the former case, $H$ must be discrete, and you know how to conclude. In the other case, $G$ connected implies $H = G$. But $H$ is a proper subgroup, so this case does not occur.

Comment: Why $\mathfrak{h}=0$ implies $H$ is discrete? Also, why if $H$ is a proper subgroup the case does not occur? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Lie algebra of $H$ is isomorphic to the tangent space of $H$ at the identity, so in particular $\dim \mathfrak h = \dim H$. Then if $\dim \mathfrak h = 0$, $H$ has dimension $0$, so it is discrete. By definition, a proper subgroup of a group is a subgroup that in particular does not coincide with the whole group. So $H$ cannot equal $G$.